# Print meaning of first letter

Tags: python

If I have a list like:

```
Q = Quiet
J = John
```

I want to print the meaning of the first letter in:

```
Queer
Johnson
```

How do I do that?  I want to take the meaning of Q from Queer and J from Johnson and print it in list form.

Output:

```
Quiet
John
```

Comment: lol what? everything is wrong with this question, but start by providing a valid python data structure that represents your "list" (though what you are describing is clearly not a list), and the code you've attempted so far - or at least some pseudo code with the individual steps so we can help

Answer (score 1):

```
handleNameChange(name):
    if(name[0] == 'Q'):
        print("Quiet");
    else:
        print("John");

a = input()
b = input()

handleNameChange(a);
handleNameChange(b)
```

Input:

```
Queer
Johnson
```

Output:

```
Quiet
John
```

Comment: Do approve my answer if you like.

Answer (score 0):

```py
meaning = {'Q': 'Quiet', 'J': 'John'}
user_input = 'Queer Johnson'
result_list = list(map(lambda x: meaning[x[0]], user_input.split()))
print(result_list)
```

Output

```py
['Quiet', 'John']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear, but I'll make an assumption that you actually need a dictionary, rather than a list, in order to create a "pseudo" translator of sorts

```
dictionary = {'Q': 'Quiet', 'J':'John'}
```

Subsequently, I assume you'd like to extract capital letters from your string, which can be done by using regex (one of many solutions)

```
import re
string = "Queer Johnson"
capital_letters = re.findall(r'[A-Z]', string)
```

Output:

```
['Q','J']
```

You can then use the dictionary to "translate" extracted letters

```
results = [v for i in capital_letters for k,v in dictionary.items() if i == k]
```

Output:

```
['Quiet', 'John']
```

P.S. Make sure your questions are properly constructed. It will help both you and the community.
Cheers!